# Grouping character strings

Tags: php, regex

I have 3 text :

- Simple test 1 [https://www.test.com/aaa/bbb#rrr] [1.111111, 0.222222]
- Simple test 2 [https://www.test.com/aaa/bbb#rrr]
- Simple test 3

I'm looking to get this :

```
    0 => Simple test 1
    1 => [https://www.test.com/aaa/bbb#rrr]
    2 => [1.111111, 0.222222]
    
    0 => Simple test 2
    1 => [https://www.test.com/aaa/bbb#rrr]
    
    0 => Simple test 3
```

With this it's ok for the first :

```
    (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\]
```

For the other two it does not work.

Any idea ?
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the square brackets, you have to put them inside the capture group.

You can make the last 2 capture groups optional inside a non capture group, where you would also make the leading space part of the optional group.

Instead of a non greedy dot, you can use a negated character class and wrap the pattern between anchors.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwvnRK/1)

```
^([^][]+)(?: (\[[^][]*\])(?: (\[[^][\n]*\]))?)?$
```